# Repair database based on two tables

Tags: mysql, database, repair

I came back here for another question related to my previous ones. A while ago I created a simple web products parser app which helped me to save some prices on different websites and do some comparison but after a while I found a relative big problem. I will explain everything below.

I have a lot of Mysql tables with the following format:

- `products` with id, name, link
- `products-prices` with id, id_prod, price, availability and date

As you can see, in the `products-prices` table there is a cell with id_prod which links to the id in the `products` table. When I parsed the link for every product I though they are unique but in reality something happened and for every product I have 3-4 links. For example, let's consider www.example.com/smth, instead of putting it parsed like that (without http/s and / at the final) in DB I put the whole link and for some reason now I have 4 different products (basically the same one) with http://www.example.com/smth, https://www.example.com/smth, http://www.example.com/smth/, https://www.example.com/smth/. Now I want to do a query to repair my database, basically to delete 1 to 3 entries and keep only one product from `products` and also change the id_prod from every entry in `products-prices`.

I don't want a direct answer, instead if you can route me to a tutorial/concept of what syntax I need to use I will be more than thankful. Have a good day!

Edit, real world example

- https://images2.imgbox.com/f5/a5/0bdvqXcu_o.png
- https://images2.imgbox.com/22/e8/BTbPLCzE_o.png

In the first picture, you can see that the only difference between those 3 products is the link, and in the link the only difference is that one of them is http the other ones are https and between those 2 https one has a slash at the final. In the second picture I have a lot (yea I know very inefficient) of entries which I want in this example to point to the product with id 2 from the first picture.

Comment: simplest question is is it a one to one relationship between these tables?

Comment: if you have more than one prodID in both any of your tables then you will get the product of all records where the ID's match

Comment: For one product I have a lot of prices, let's say I have in products the following entries in the first table(id, name, link): 1,'iPhone7',http://example.com/iphone7; 2,'iPhone7',https://example.com/iphone7;3,'iPhone7',http://example.com/iphone7 and in the second one with the prices(id, id_prod, price, availability, date): 1,1,500,'In stock',10PM;2,1,600,'In Stock',12PM;3,2,400,'In Stock',12PM;4,3,400,'In Stock',12PM. I want to delete 2 entries from first table and the ones from the second to point to the first one entry.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that somehow the website updated itself or something and when I scraped the link for the product it appeared with s or one slash at the final, they are now different products but they are the same and I want for the future to store only www.example.com without http/s or slash at the final.

Comment: so first you'd have to `UPDATE` the prices table to change the prod_id to the ID of the product you want to keep. You have to do this first otherwise you break referential integrity. Then you `DELETE` from the products table `WHERE` the ID matches the ID(s) you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple grouping to ascertain the scale of the problem:

```
 SELECT (COUNTPRODID) C, PRODID
 FROM YOURTABLE
 GROUP BY PRODID
 HAVING COUNT(PRODID) >1
```

Once you have identified the scale of the issue, you could create a table to stage 1 of your records with a sequence based on the PRODID as below:

```
 SELECT * INTO TmpTable
 FROM
 (SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
    WHEN @PRODID  = PRODID THEN @row_number + 1
    ELSE 1
   END AS SEQ,
   @PRODID :=PRODID as PRODID
   FROM
   YOURTABLE
   ORDER BY PRODID;) dups
WHERE dups.SEQ = 1
```

You could then delete all rows in you source

```
 DELETE FROM YOURTABLE
 WHERE PRODID IN (SELECT PRODID FROM TmpTable)
```

And then finally write the rows back from your temp table:

```
 INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
 SELECT field1, field2 etc. FROM TmpTable
```

Comment: I would also hazard a guess that you have a delimiter incorrect somewhere and that is why you are getting extra rows when writing rows. This may be a good place to start looking.

Comment: This is not valid MySQL syntax

Comment: ROW_NUMBER doesn't exist at all in MySQL until version 8, which most mysql hosts don't use, and there's no other direct equivalent, so that's a fairly big problem. I haven't got a full answer (hence my comment) but then if you haven't got one which actually works then I'd argue it's not a useful answer - which is the reason for the downvote. Although you should note for the future you can't assume it was me who downvoted. In this case I happily admit to it, but you have no way to prove it, so best not to make accusations.

Comment: Thanks @Adyson, I have updated my answer to use the older MySQL syntax, the approach remains the same. Also I might add, the OP asked for an approach not a direct answer " don't want a direct answer, instead if you can route me to a tutorial/concept" the theory holds water thanks for your input.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution, first of all I need to find duplicate products, to do that I need to check in the first table (products) the link, if I have 2/3/4 similar links (similar = http or https or .com/ or .com should be the only difference between them) then I need to change in the second table all products with those id's to the first one let's say and then delete from the first table.

Comment: If you can provide some sample data we can then advise further - Thanks

Comment: I provided 2 pictures in the first post, if needed I can export 2 tables.

Comment: Would be good to see what the data looks like at table level - thanks

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/16f0827304b7b9ae816e35fafb4d6db320180215160101/22d521 I added 2 tables, laptop-desktop-it/laptopuri and laptop-desktop-it/laptopuri-p. For example this query "SELECT * FROM `laptop-desktop-it/laptopuri` WHERE `name` LIKE '%mlha2roa%'" will return id 24 and 600. I need to delete id 600 record and all products from 2nd table (the one with -p) to change their id_prod 600 to 24.

Comment: Hi there the theory remains correct, I have provided a solution that can be customised to use any sequence based on the way you sequence the records. what sets Id 24 and 600 apart that you could use to sequence them, and then apply this to the records filtered into the temp table. I'm assuming your tables have relationships and keys defined? If so your deletes can be cascaded to preserve referential integrity.

Comment: I don't think they have relationships defined, keys maybe like primary key id in the first and second one. I don't think that mysql have any ideea that my id_prod is referring to id from the first table. I do that using php and the way I insert them. In your solution how may I sequence them based on the ones that differ only by http/https and/or slash or without it at the end ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I would suggest taking copies of everything and start adapting the sql to run on your copied tables, one thing you can always derive a natural sequence from is if a number for one numeric I'd is greater than the other.